# questions about an SD card

Tags: sd-card, encryption

I encrypted my cell phone with my SD card in it. Recently my phone was stolen I managed to get it back but they stole my SD card. So I was wondering even though they stole my SD card would my files still be encrypted or will they be able to see them.

Thanks

Comment: They would not be able to see the contents of encrypted card without the phone, since encryption is tied with the device. Exception possible if they are highly skilled and the information is important enough for then to invest hugely. Adding OS details to your question and if it is adoptable-storage would help

Comment: And when they had the phone, they could have simply connected it to a laptop and copied the contents of SD.